# unset multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having a hell of a time with this. I have a multidimensional array that I am storing in a session.

```
$d1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$d2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$d3 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$d4 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_SESSION['array1'] = array($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4);
```

what I want to do is remove the $d2 array from the session array1

however when I do something like this

```
unset($_SESSION['array1'][1]);
```

you would think that $_SESSION['array1'] would then = array($d1,$d3,$d4);

however what that does is actually unset the whole session variable.

Then if I try something like

```
foreach ($_SESSION['array1'] as $k => $v) {
echo "The Key is $k: The Value is $v";
}
```

however that gives me an error

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The only conclusion that I can come to is that the session variable is being completely unset, not that just the specific key is being removed from the array.

is there any way that i can unset a specific value contained within an array that is part of a session variable?

Comment: There must be something else wrong in the code. Try commenting out the `unset(...)` line and `var_dump`ing the `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you present works as expected:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
session_start();
$d1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$d2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$d3 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$d4 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_SESSION['array1'] = array($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4);
unset($_SESSION['array1'][1]); 
print_R($_SESSION);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [array1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ...
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    ...
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    ...
                )

        )

)
```

So some debugging ideas:

1. Don't use `@session_start`.
2. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
3. Configure error reporting in php.ini
4. Check your cookies to see whether the PHPSESSID cookie was sent at all.

Comment: thanks, I fogot to do session_start at the beginning of the script

Comment: Please, still have a look at sємsєм's answer. It's good to have arrays ordered like `(0, 1, 2 ...)`. `unset` does not keep that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) as the following code shows:

```
$_SESSION['array1'] = array_splice($_SESSION['array1'],1,0);
```

Comment: Very good point, unset leaves one offset skipped: `(0, 2, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

How about storing your session variable again:

```
$_SESSION['array1'] = array($d1,$d3,$d4);
```